# PowerBI Visuals Tools - error after pbiviz start command

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

I trying to start my custom visual (like usually) but after I updated `powerbi-custom-visual` to version beta **3.0.11** from version **3.0.10** I got the following error:

```
error  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mar/CustomVisuals/rangechart/.tmp/precompile/visualPlugin.ts'
(node:1454) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to generate visualPlugin.ts
   at generateVisualPlugin.then.catch.ex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/powerbi-visuals-tools/node_modules/powerbi-visuals-webpack-plugin/index.js:168:12)
   at <anonymous>
```

Does anyone knows why is that? I returned back to the previous beta version of `powerbi-custom-visual` but it did not help. With version **2.3.0** everything works fine.

Comment: Hello, do you use new approach to visual development or just try to compile old visual project created by stable version of tools?

Comment: @Ilfat Galiev. New approach. I started to use v. 3.0.9. without problems. Later I updated to v. 3.0.10, also successfully. Problem started after update to 3.0.11. Problem did not disappeared when I moved back to 3.10. In fact I have the same error when I want to start purely new visual created with "pbiviz new newvisual"

Comment: 3.0.12 version of tools was released. Could you check your case? Does the problem get away?

Comment: @IlfatGaliev Yes, it does. With 3.0.12 everything works fine.

Comment: @IlfatGaliev i upgraded from 3.0.10 to 3.0.12 and got this error. ```ERROR in ./.tmp/precompile/visualPlugin.ts 5:4
Module parse failed: Identifier 'NPSTableVisual' has already been declared (5:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var powerbi = window[powerbiKey];
|
> var NPSTableVisual-e13987b0-3aaa-4ff8-a49e-3b75d655ef77_DEBUG = {
|     name: 'NPSTableVisual-e13987b0-3aaa-4ff8-a49e-3b75d655ef77_DEBUG',
|     displayName: 'NPS Table',
 @ multi ./.tmp/precompile/visualPlugin.ts visual.js[0]```

Comment: @IlfatGaliev even after going back to 3.0.10 it's not working

Comment: @IlfatGaliev server is not started in localhost:8080

Comment: @Dangling_pointer It' seems you used wrong name for visual class and GUID. Could you share pbiviz.json file?

Comment: @IlfatGaliev Got the issue, it was because my guid has `-` in it. Didn't know guid is being used as a variable name, figured it out after looking inside `.tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar after I deleted the .tmp folder in my project to clean up from an old build. I found that I had to manually (re)create the .tmp/precompile directories inside my project folder. Not sure why the tool couldn't handle creating them itself.